# Java - Where is my ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException coming from?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write code that takes in words and stores their letters in a multi-dimensional array. Right now, I'm getting an array index out of bounds exception and I don't know why. I am testing it with the following input:

```
2
SEND
MORE
MONEY
```

(I'm only trying to get the letters of 'SEND' and 'MORE' into the array.)

I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at the indicated line. Here is my code:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
String[] addends = new String[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    addends[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
}
String sum = keyboard.nextLine();

int maxWordLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (addends[i].length() > maxWordLength)
        maxWordLength = addends[i].length();

char[][] letters = new char[maxWordLength][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < addends[i].length(); j++)
        letters[i][j] = addends[i].charAt(j);       //Getting exception here.

//Test that letters were added correctly
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < addends[i].length(); j++)
        System.out.print(letters[i][j]);
```

Comment: It is coming from the line indicated in the stack trace which you failed to include in your question.

Comment: Have you tried debugging step by step or adding debug output?

Comment: @EJP the line is indicated by a comment in the code. No worries though, I realized my mistake. But thanks for being condescending.

Answer (score 3):

```
char[][] letters = new char[maxWordLength][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < addends[i].length(); j++)
        letters[i][j] = addends[i].charAt(j);
```

It is obvious by inspection that the first line should be

```
char[][] letters = new char[n][maxWordLength];
```

or else that you have `i` and `j` mixed up in the following loops.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how I didn't notice that right away. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
char[][] letters = new char[maxWordLength][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < addends[i].length(); j++)
        letters[i][j] = addends[i].charAt(j);
```

Your conditionals for i and j are mismatched; i should stop at addends[i].length() and j should stop a